# How to unfold lines in ex mode?

Tags: folding

`1,100fo` can fold lines from beginning to 100th line in ex mode,i can unfold the lines in normal mode with `zo` and just click `enter` to expand it in insert mode,now how can unfold it in ex mode?`1,100nofo` and `1,100unfo`  can't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`:foldopen`](https://vimhelp.org/fold.txt.html#%3Afoldopen) command to open all folds in a range. You can also shorten it to `:foldo`. So, in your case, `:1,100foldo` would do.

Note that what this does is **open** the folds, which is not really the inverse operation to **creating** the folds (which is what `:fold` does.) The inverse operation would be to delete the folds (which you can do with [`zd`](https://vimhelp.org/fold.txt.html#zd) or perhaps `zD`.) There is no command to delete folds directly from Ex, you would have to use something like `:normal! zd` to call the corresponding Normal mode command.